# How to read from the Google credentials json file

Tags: php, json, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm using the Youtube Data Api v3 and I want to use the json form to get the Client ID from OAuth and the client secret, also the app name too, but I don't know how to call the JSON object.

My code look like this:

```
$application_name = 'StackOverflow'; 
$client_secret = 'xxxxxx';
$client_id = 'xxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com';
$scope = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtubepartner');

$videoPath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/apiyoutube/google-api/xxx.avi";
```

Instead of this, I want to get the all of above Id's from the JSON to use the api in a safe way.

Comment: You might want to consider using the php client library https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client

Comment: Yep, done, I just need to put $client->setAuthConfigFile('client_secret.json'); and work. Thank You!